# Out of Memory Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, installation

I am trying to install Spring framework in my eclipse ganymede through an update site http://springide.org/updatesite. But when it updates an error will occur in my ide which says that an out of memory error occurred.

Comment: Try it with latest eclipse, latest JDK and this eclipse.ini: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to raise the memory settings in the eclipse.ini.

I am using

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: I already edited the ini file but I still get the same error... and even though I have 1Gb of ram.... here's my current ini file


-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: You have only 1gig of ram in your machine? If that's the case then you might consider upgrading to at least 2gig ram. Eclipse is sometimes pretty greedy and your OS and other running apps consume their share of the memory too, which may lead to our out of memory problem.

Comment: ah ok... So it is really a hardware problem... but i tried pasting this in the ini...

-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup
/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in windows, Try to use a different instance of Java then the your default one(c:/programfiles...). 
- Copy the JDK folder somewhere in your D:/ drive
- In eclipse go to Preferences-> BuildPath
- Point to the alternate JDK you just created

Many cases that might solve the problem as well.